# Find path on continuous big map with obstacles

Tags: algorithm, graph, game-engine

I am trying to create game on continuous board ( no grid cells) with some obstacles ( like boxes and ruined walls at random points, map is big). What algorithm can I use to solve this ( is something similar A* in grid boards) ? I kinda done a little research, can I use Voronoi diagram for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Skiena's *The Algorithm Design Manual* is an entry under computational geometry called "motion planning". It lists a few implementations for that, the *Motion Planning Toolkit*, *SWIFT++* and *CGAL*. If you can, take a look at that book, I found it very pragmatic to read, and while it doesn't really offer many solutions, it always has a few pointers where to find them. Basically, an approach is to generate a suitable graph from the map and then to use Dijkstra's Algorithm (or maybe A*?) to find the shortest way. Generating the graph requires analyzing which points you can move between without crossing an obstagle.

Comment: Would you really use BFS?  Wouldn't that assume all edges have the same cost?

Comment: Yep, you're completely right. Of course you search with increasing  cost, not with increasing edge count.

Comment: @doomster- Isn't that Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: Yes, and I just fixed what I wrote. Thanks!